# Actionable messages for internal LOB workflows

Tags: office365connectors

Can i used actionable messages in Outlook for my internal LOB workflows?
I want it enabled only for my Office 365 organization

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use Actionable Messages (AM) for your internal LOB. The platform has capability of enabling actionable messages for a given organization.

Please fill up some details in the registration form on the developer dashboard link given in our documentation and we will follow up with you further.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/actionable-email-dev-dashboard

Regards,
Vasant

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use actionable messages for your line of business workflows. Ensure that your **action target URLs are internet reachable**. As a developer you would have access to send actionable messages to yourself. To be able to send actionable messages to others you would have to **register your email sender domain and action targets in the Actionable Messages Developer dashboard** (in your case with the scope 'My Organization').

[Actionable Messages Developer Dashboard](https://aka.ms/publishoam)

[Documentation: Register your service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/actionable-email-dev-dashboard)